# No return value when scraping

Tags: python, loops, append

I am trying to scrape a property website - it's 38 pages. In a previous version my code only returned the specified values on the first page. So I added a page range. I did ask on reedit and someone said "appending to lists in your pages loop instead of setting it in each iteration" but I'm not entirely sure how to do this or where I went wrong. Could someone help me here? I want to return "info = [price, address]" on all 38 pages.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for pages in range(1,38):
    url = requests.get("https://rah.co.uk/property_area/to-buy/{page}.html".format(page =pages))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml")
    list = soup.select("ct-div-block property-outer")
    lists = soup.select("ct-div-block property-outer")

for lis in lists:
    price = lis.find("li", class_ ="ct-code-block property-price").text
    address = lis.find("li", class_ ="ct-text-block property-name").text
    info = [price, address]
    print(info)
```

Expected a return on all values in the 38 pages, so it loops "ct-div-block property-outer" on multiple pages.

Comment: Each time you assign `lists = soup.select("ct-div-block property-outer")`, you're recreating `lists` as a **brand new** variable, and you're throwing away its contents from the prior loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you got on reddit is right. This is what the change looks like:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

lists = []  # ********************************************** ADDED LINE
for pages in range(1,38):
        url = requests.get("https://rah.co.uk/property_area/to-buy/{page}.html".format(page =pages))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml")
        # ********************************************** START CHANGED LINES
        relevant_content = soup.select("ct-div-block property-outer")
        lists.append(relevant_content)
        # ********************************************** END CHANGED LINES


for lis in lists:
        price = lis.find("li", class_ ="ct-code-block property-price").text
        address = lis.find("li", class_ ="ct-text-block property-name").text
        info = [price, address]
        print(info)
```

*A note on code style and formatting:*

1. Consider using a code editor (e.g `VSCode`, `PyCharm`) with a python code formatter (e.g. `black`). This will help with code style issues like `class_ ="...`.
2. Ensure names are logical e.g. `page=pages` doesn't read
   logically. Renaming `page` to `pages` in your loop would make this read as `page=page`, which does read logically.
3. DRY (Don't repeat yourself) and avoid using keywords as variable names. I replaced the lines

```
list = soup.select("ct-div-block property-outer")
lists = soup.select("ct-div-block property-outer")
```

with

```
lists.append(...)
```

The first line shadowed the built-in `list`.

Answer (score -1):

There's a few issues with your code:

- The URL (format string) you are querying is not correct.  It's missing a "page" path parameter.  E.g. `https://rah.co.uk/property_area/to-buy/1.html` points to an error handling page.  Instead you want something like `https://rah.co.uk/property_area/to-buy/page/5`.
- The format string is putting in the wrong variable.  You have `pages` when it should just be `page`.  Actually what you have is correct, but you should rename it to `page` so its more clear what the intent is.
- On another line you are assigning a reserved keyword `list` to a BeautifulSoup selector result.  You should rename this to something like `property_list` instead.

So I would change the variable `url` to look like this instead:

```py
for page in range(1,38):
  url = requests.get("https://rah.co.uk/property_area/to-buy/page/{page}".format(page=page))
```